# How can I make sure that PDO's lastInsertId() is not that of another simultaneous insert?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am doing a signup form with an `INSERT` SQL query using PDO. After this INSERT, I want to extract the `userid` (auto incrementing, primary key) that was just created, and `INSERT` it into another table (a "confirmation code" table)

But how can I make sure that this userid is not that of a second user who registered 1/1000th of a second later that the first user?

Should I find some way of locking the table? Should I use transactions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`lastInsertId()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php) returns the identifier of the last row inserted *on that connection*, so concurrent users (with different connections to the database) will not interfere.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I will then use that with no worry. regards

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid this by doing a select by the email or some unique field. That will guarantee you get the correct user id.

For example:

```
select id from user_table where email = 'user@email.com' limit 1;
```

Comment: Hi, I wanted to use the lastInsertId() but I will keep your tip in mind. Thanks a lot.