# PHP PDO::lastInsertId() and ATTR_PERSISTENT

Tags: php, pdo, last-insert-id

I have almost the same question as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711966/how-can-i-make-sure-that-pdos-lastinsertid-is-not-that-of-another-simultaneou).

Based on that post I know that PDO::lastInsertId() is safe when called from different connections. However, does this mean `PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true` should *not* be used in the PDO constructor if you want to use PDO::lastInsertId() during that connection?

In other words, if I need to use PDO::lastInsertId() is my application compelled to endure "the overhead of establishing a new connection every time a script needs to talk to a database" as documented in [PDO Connections and Connection Management](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't mean.

Doesn't matter who will utilize the same connection after your php script ends its work. What matters is that you will have the last inserted id that's performed by this, not another connection.

So feel free to use it with both persistent and not-persistent connections.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Is this your interpretation or could you point me to somewhere in the documentation where this is explicitly stated?

Comment: @Alien Bishop: I doubt there is some explicit statement in documentation. It's obvious - `lastInsertId()` returns the last id from the current connection. As simple as 1+1. Doesn't matter where the connection has been got from and where it goes after.

Comment: Right. So what if Alice and Bob are sharing the same connection, and this happens? Alice inserts, Bob inserts, Bob calls lastInsertId(), Alice calls lastInsertId(). Since they had the same connection, Alice doesn't get the wrong result?

Comment: @Alien Bishop: they cannot share the same connection. Connection (either persistent or not) can only be used by one script in a moment. Persistent means that after your script ends the work - the connection goes to a special pool and when another script needs new connection - it is given to that script.

Comment: Ahh, ok. The persistence of the connection doesn't mean two people somehow use it simultaneously. It merely means the connection is cached and reused (one user at a time). Got it. Thanks!